# svn commit: to which "--encoding" parameter applies?

Tags: svn, encoding, utf-8, properties

I have to make svn commit with both UTF-8 commit message and UTF-8-encoded revision property.

If I call:

```
svn ci -F commit_message.UTF8.file --with-revprop prop1='UTF8-value1' --encoding 'utf-8'
```

will UTF-8 from *--encoding* parameter applied both to commit message file (commit_message.UTF8.file) and specified 'prop1' revision property value (UTF8-value1)?

I know that it possible adding revision property later with *svn propset --revprop -r NNN* but It will be nice to make all in one operation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The commit messages are always stored in UTF-8 (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.tour.initial.html):

> Subversion internally handles certain bits of data—for example, property names, pathnames, and log messages—as UTF-8-encoded Unicode. This is not to say that all your interactions with Subversion must involve UTF-8, though. As a general rule, Subversion clients will gracefully and transparently handle conversions between UTF-8 and the encoding system in use on your computer, if such a conversion can meaningfully be done (which is the case for most common encodings in use today).